# Oracle Apex return column based on minus results in case

Tags: oracle-apex

I need help with rewriting my IG query.

IG Query:

```
select validated, emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employees;
```

I have another table:

```
select  emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employee_admin;
```

I need to compare both tables and if

```
select  emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employees;
minus
select  emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation,emp_hier from employee_admin;
```

returns 0 rows, the validated column should show Y, else N.

I need to add this logic in the sql query itself if possible.

Comment: That sample code compares the result of 2 queries. What are you expecting as value for each individual row ? Maybe you could add in more detail to your question what it is you're expecting as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one option based on the way I understood the question.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> with
  2  employees (validated, emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation, emp_hier) as
  3    (select 'X', 1, 'Little', 'design', 2 from dual),
  4  employee_admin (emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation, emp_hier) as
  5    (select 1, 'Little', 'design', 2 from dual)
```

Query begins here:

```
  6  select emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation, emp_hier,
  7    --
  8    (select case when exists (select emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation, emp_hier from employees
  9                              minus
 10                              select emp_id, emp_name, emp_designation, emp_hier from employee_admin
 11                             ) then 'N'
 12                 else 'Y'
 13            end
 14     from dual
 15    ) as validated
 16  from employees;

    EMP_ID EMP_NAME        EMP_DESIGNATION        EMP_HIER VALIDATED
---------- --------------- -------------------- ---------- ---------------
         1 Little          design                        2 Y

SQL>
```